# Get notification on Ctrl+Alt+Del

Tags: windows, keyboard, notifications

I know there is no way to block or ignore <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> within a program. But thats not what I want. Is there a way to only be notified if it WAS pressed? No interaction required, only notification.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Are you trying to find out if the user has locked the workstation?

Comment: Any particular programming language?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect Ctrl-Alt-Del either before or after the OS detects it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090930/how-can-i-detect-ctrl-alt-del-either-before-or-after-the-os-detects-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem that there is an easy way to get a [SAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721625%28VS.85%29.aspx#_security_secure_attention_sequence_gly) notification, all articles I've found dealt with replacing [GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375457%28VS.85%29.aspx).

You might want to take a look at these:

- [Customizing GINA, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx)
- [Customizing GINA, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163786.aspx)
- [C++ Q&A Typename, Disabling Keys in Windows XP with TrapKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188951.aspx)

If you only want to find out whether the user has locked his workstation, you should take a look at [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841%28VS.85%29.aspx) in conjunction with [WM_WTSESSION_CHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, and I have a suspicion there's probably a better and cleaner way to accomplish your ultimate goal, but...

Off the top of my head, I would run a timer in the background of your application, and each time the timer fires, check to see if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> , <kbd>Alt</kbd> , and  <kbd>Delete</kbd>  keys were pressed. To do that, you'll have to use [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293(VS.85).aspx) from user32.dll. I'd give you a code sample, but I'm not sure what language you're using. Play around with the interval for the timer to see what it needs to be to balance performance, yet still work.

Comment: There is a VB example from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/77a366f9-46a9-49e1-9665-56a3258ba39b .